# Problems with SLE4428 smart card

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I have EZ100PU usb smart card reader and new (clear) SLE4428 smart cards. I would like to write number sequence on them. I'm trying to do it with simple java application. That's my code based on others available on the internet:

```
public class Connection {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

    TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();

    CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(1); 
    System.out.println("terminal: " + terminal.getName());
    Card card = terminal.connect("*");
    System.out.println("card: " + card);
    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel(); 
    System.out.println("channel: " + channel.getChannelNumber());
    System.out.println("protocol: "+card.getProtocol());

    byte b[]=card.getATR().getBytes();
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
       System.out.print(b[i]);


//        byte[] bytes = {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x00};
//        ResponseAPDU r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(bytes));

    card.disconnect(false);

  }
}
```

I have problem, because I always get "Unknown protocol 16" when card is inside reader. Probably because of that I can't write anything on the card, if I try I always get error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a method of connecting to ISO 7816-3 (T=0, T=1 or T=CL) compatible processor cards to connect to a lowly memory card. You will likely have to use a card specific reader library instead, you cannot just use `javax.smartcardio`.

Comment: So can you tell me is it possible to get those libraries and how to get it? Or maybe it will be easier to use different smard cards - which would you recommend just to write short number sequence on them?

Comment: The cards are fine for that purpose, but you should contact your supplier for a good combination of reader and library.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know who is original supplier, because I bought reader and cards as used from a private person. So I think it would be easier just to buy different smart cards. If you could recommend some cards I should buy to easy write on them (e.g. using javax.smartcardio or other different simple method) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: In general the memory cards are probably best for this kind of use, so I would stick to them and look for the required library from the reader manufacturer. They should be pretty common cards, so likely there should be a few. They are also likely to come with C/C++ header files though, so you may need JNI to communicate with Java. javax.smartcardio is probably not such a good idea for this, it's too high level. If you *do* go that way you might want to think about a DESFire card, which should contain a (pretty simple) APDU interface.

Comment: Hello sir, it's me again. I decided to use different type of smart cards because I wasn't able to find any way to write or read from my SLE4428 cards. I was looking for DESFire cards you said but from what I found it's only available in contactless version. So I would need contact smart card with, like you said, simple APDU. Could you name some cards like I need? Unfortunately I couldn't find it. As I see you're familiar with smard cards and I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: APDU stands for Application Protocol Data Unit. It kind of requires an application to be there, so you could try to find a file system card that contains a simple processor and no additional asymmetric coprocessors. Unfortunately, my realm is almost entirely on the high end part of the contactless smart card market. I would have to look into the current situation first before I could make any kind of recommendation - except for the one I already made: you really don't need APDU's to read/write sequence numbers. Look for a development set of reader and smart cards.

Comment: I found libraries for my card reader and I used my SLE4428 smart cards. Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Comment: Would you mind sharing where you found the libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Your SLE 4428 card has default PIN = FFFF. 
First you need to verify PIN USING below COMMAND :- 
FF 20 00 00 02 FFFF
Then you can write data to SLE 4428 card. 
If data is "My name is Kashyap" then in hex it is 4D79206E616D65206973204B617368796170. 
Write Data:- 
FF D0 00 20 12 4D79206E616D65206973204B617368796170. 
You can also change default PIN. Suppose I want to chagne PIN to 1234 from FFFF then 
use below Command:- 
FF D0 03 FD 03 FF 1234.

To read data below command:-
FF B0 00 20 12

Thanks,
Kashyap